# Excel Formula to combine AVERAGE, OFFSET, IF, ISNUMBER

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a formula that will allow me to find the average of every nth cell, where n is specified by the user in another cell, however there are many #N/A cells in my data range and I wish to ignore these values when calculating the average.

This is what I have so far; it takes the data in cell C3 and returns the average value of every nth cell in cell D3, and n is specified in cell L11.

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($C$3, (ROW() - ROW($D$3))*$L$11,,$L$11,))
```

This works perfectly but fails when there is a #N/A in the range, returning #N/A. I have tried this formula below but it only returns the correct value for the first n cells but returns 0 for the rest.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER((OFFSET($C$3, (ROW() - ROW($G$3))*$L$11,,$L$11,))),(OFFSET($C$3, (ROW() - ROW($G$3))*$L$11,,$L$11,))))
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you enter it as an Array Formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)?

Comment: @z32a7ul When I enter it as an array formula, it returns #DIV/0!, but when I press enter like for a normal formula, it works, but only for the first cell.

Comment: And if you write Sum instead of Average, does it return 0?

Comment: @z32a7ul Yes, it returns 0 for all except the first cell! How strange.

Comment: As I see, you supplied $L$11 as the third parameter to Offset. Are you sure, you need it? That makes you have n rows heigh ranges.

Comment: What is `(ROW() - ROW($D$3))` in this formula supposed to do? In row 3 it will be 0 and so `Offset` will offset 0. In row 4 it will be 1 and so  `Offset` will offset 1 * `L11`. In row 5 it will be 2 and so  `Offset` will offset 2 * `L11`. I suspect this is not what you want. In general you could use `AVARAGEIF` like so: `=AVERAGEIF(OFFSET($C$3,(ROW()-ROW($D$3))*$L$11,,$L$11),"<>#N/A")`

Answer (score 0):

if `#N/A` is the result of a formula, just add an `IFERROR` to your formulas it & make the result `""`. example: `"=IFERROR([formula here],"")`